# "unsupported collating sort order" when trying to read from Access using Jackcess (Java)

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I'm currently working on a Java application with the purpuose of reading a Microsoft Access file using Jackcess open source library. The Java application will later present the tables contained in the Access file.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("\\\\student.local\\Files\\Home\\nat12mja\\Downloads\\Testdoc.accdb");
        Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(file);

        Table table = db.getTable("Table1");

        for(Row row : table){
            System.out.println(row.get("Field1"));
        }    

    }
}
```

These are my imports:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
    import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;
```

Also, I've added these Jar files to my referenced librarys:

commons-lang-2.4.jar, commons-logging-1.1.jar, jackcess-2.0.2.jar

When I run my application I get this error message(The System.out.println() works as intended):

```
    dec 21, 2013 1:54:27 EM com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData setUnsupportedReason
    WARNING: unsupported collating sort order SortOrder[1053(0)] for text index, making read-only
    dec 21, 2013 1:54:27 EM com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl readSystemCatalog
    INFO: Could not find expected index on table MSysObjects
```

I've tested with older versions of the same Access file, but the problem persists.

Is this a library related problem? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: why don't you use jdbc? there must be a driver for ms-access

Comment: I am working on this too. I want both to work tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jackcess only supports indexes on `Text` fields in an Access database when the database is using the "General" sort order (ref: [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/bugs/86/)).

According to the related [Microsoft Office support page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/select-settings-for-how-data-is-displayed-and-stored-in-your-database-HA010341912.aspx):

> To reset the sort order for an existing database, select the language you want to use and then run a compact operation on the database.

So, for Access 2010 that would presumably mean selecting `File > Options` from the Access ribbon bar, choosing "General" or "General - Legacy" for the "New database sort order" on the "General" tab, ...

[image: screenshot]

... then performing a "Compact and Repair" on the database.

**Note:** If Windows is using a non-English locale then the procedure described above might not rectify the problem. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972659/2144390) for details.