# Ms Access makes database read-only and couldn't be updated with Java

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I have in my project a Ms Access database which worked fine before, now after formatting my computer I've run my project and It worked but when I opened the database with MsAccess 2007 and closed it. It won't get updated with the Java project.

I still have copies of database which wasn't opened with MsAccess and it works fine if I use it. so the problem is opening the database with MS Access - it kind of lock it read-only ( that's what the Jackcess says )

Comment: have you created DSN for database connectivity ?

Comment: I didn't create DSN, I use jackcess directly with the directory of the .accdb file :
String dbFileSpec = "src\\database.accdb";

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer of one of the posts, It's the version of MsAccess It made the sort order French despite of General.

Here the answer by @Gord Thompson : ["unsupported collating sort order" when trying to read from Access using Jackcess (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719417/unsupported-collating-sort-order-when-trying-to-read-from-access-using-jackces)